# What's the difference between these two input statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried using these two input statements in python. Both the statements returns same output. What's the difference between using `split()` and `split(" ")` ?

```
a=[int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
print(a)
```

and

```
a=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(a)
```

Comment: No difference; does the same thing. `split` by default splits on whitespace.

Comment: If no parameter is passed to ``split()``, input is split by spaces by default

Comment: This is clearly described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). That, not posting a new question on this site, should be your first resort.

Comment: try on your python console `help(str.split)` to get better understanding what `split` function accomplishes.

Answer (score 1):

The default action of method `split` on a string is to split on *any* grouping of white space:

```
>>> 'foo   bar'.split()
['foo', 'bar']
>>> 'foo \n \t   bar'.split()
['foo', 'bar']
```

If you pass a literal space as the argument, however, the split is done differently, with *only* a literal space as the splitter, and with empty strings resulting from adjacent literal spaces:

```
>>> 'foo \n \t   bar'.split(' ')
['foo', '\n', '\t', '', '', 'bar']
```

If the input has only single, ordinary spaces, there will be no observable difference.